# TSQL include accounts with condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have a table currently including all accounts like this:

[image]

I need to filter where if Company = MMCR and HSSA AND Days sent >= 90, then I need the report to include the companies. All other companies are included regardless of Days sent.

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't account 4 be left out as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `OR`:

```
SELECT Account, Invoice, Company, DaysSent
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Company NOT IN('MMCR', 'HSSA')
       OR (Company IN('MMCR', 'HSSA') AND DaysSent >= 90);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler than the other answers:

```
SELECT [Account], [Invoice #], [Company], [Days Sent]
FROM [dbo].[YourTable]
WHERE NOT ([Company] IN ('MMCR', 'HSSA') AND [Days Sent] < 90);
```

Comment: I prefer to expand that via De Morgan's Law but all the same: `(Company not in ('MMCR', 'HSSA') or "Days Sent" >= 90)`. Of course `or` often trips people up once the query gets longer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, INVOICE, COMPANY, DAYS_SENT FROM TABLE1
WHERE (COMPANY = 'MMCR' AND DAYS_SENT >= 90) OR (COMPANY = 'HSSA' AND DAYS_SENT >= 90)

UNION

SELECT ACCOUNT, INVOICE, COMPANY, DAYS_SENT FROM TABLE1
ACCOUNT NOT IN (
SELECT ACCOUNT
WHERE (COMPANY = 'MMCR' AND DAYS_SENT >= 90) OR (COMPANY = 'HSSA' AND DAYS_SENT >= 90)
)
```

- UNION the top query with the bottom query.
- The top query will contain the 2 companies with their date range
- The bottom query is everything not in the top query.

There a lot of ways to solve this, I simply like this approach as I feel it's easy to read and understand (especially much later when you want to update it!)

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can do like this  

     SELECT ACCOUNT, INVOICE, COMPANY, DAYS_SENT FROM TABLE1
        WHERE Company   in ('MMCR', 'HSSA') AND DAYS_SENT >= 90 

        UNION

        SELECT ACCOUNT, INVOICE, COMPANY, DAYS_SENT FROM TABLE1 Where 
        ACCOUNT NOT IN  ('MMCR', 'HSSA')
```